# Navigating to specific place in XPS document viewer VB.net

Tags: vb.net, xps, documentviewer, fixeddocument

I've spent 2 days trying to find the solution with no luck.

I have a XPS file which I am displaying in a document viewer, and what I want to do, is use a variable that I have, to navigate to a certain place in the document within the viewer.

Firstly, how would I set some sort of identifier within the xps document? At the moment, I have got bookmarks set in it from word and then converted to xps, which I can see in the FixedDoc file, therefore I know it can see them, but I don't know how to the utilise this.

At the moment I have:

```
Dim _XpsPackage As XpsDocument
_XpsPackage = New XpsDocument(xpsFilename, IO.FileAccess.Read)
docViewer.Document = _XpsPackage.GetFixedDocumentSequence

Dim _CurrentDocSection() As String = Split(_CurrentWindow.Title, ".", 2)

Dim docSeq As IXpsFixedDocumentSequenceReader = _XpsPackage.FixedDocumentSequenceReader
Dim doc As IXpsFixedDocumentReader = docSeq.FixedDocuments(0)

Dim a = doc.Uri
```

From here, I want to use _CurrentDocSection(1), as my identifier and then navigate to where that bookmark is within the document, but cannot seem to find it.

Thanks